# magento 2 - how to set attribute datetime display time?

Tags: magento2, attributes

how to set attribute datetime display time ?
[image]

Comment: Anyone have answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create file calendar.js below: 
path: myPool/myModule/view/adminhtml/web/js/calendar.js

```
   require([
            "jquery",
            "mage/calendar"
    ], function($){

       $("#period_date_start").calendar({
          // americanMode: false,
          //stepMinute: 15,
          showsTime: true,
            controlType: 'select',
            timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
            showTime: false,
            closeText: "Done",
            selectOtherMonths: true,
            onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#period_date_end" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
          }
       });

        $("#period_date_end").calendar({
          showsTime: true,
            controlType: 'select',
            timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
            showTime: false,
            closeText: "Done",
            selectOtherMonths: true,
          onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#period_date_start" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
          }
       });

    });
```

**warning:** Check your static content is generated this file.

Comment: i want to use slider instead of select how can I do this need help please